# How do I resolve this CollectionViewCell Constraint issue?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I can't figure out where the constraint that is being broken is coming from. I'm resizing the width of the image to the width of the screen and have an aspect ratio on it. If I remove both of them and make it a static height I don't get the error but that isn't the desired result.

What am I missing?

[image: xcodeImage]

Comment: You have a constraint to fix the width of your image to 323 that it doesn't seem like you want.

Comment: I resize it to be the size of the screen in code. If I remove it entirely the cell size isn't returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From your console, it appears there is an `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` that has been added to the list of constraints. That is usually problematic. I would suggest setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false for all views (especially ones that are added programmatically).

Comment: I added setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) on all associated views including the UIView that the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint is on with no luck. Is that being added because of the aspect ratio constraint?

Comment: When you added that was the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` still in the list of constraints that were conflicting?

Comment: Yes, it still appears in the list.

Comment: If you debug that view controller after you call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on everything, what view is that `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` on? Does it have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false?